# Generate file name on file upload that contains file's username

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I want to have the filename looks like: Username-OriginalFileName. 
My first solution was to use  the preUpload callback in my File Entity as described in Symfony cookbook [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html#using-lifecycle-callbacks)

```
  /**
  * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
   */
 public $FILE_file;

 public $path;

    public function getPath()
    {
        return $this->path;
    }
    public function setPath($path)
    {
        return $this->path=$path;
    }

    public function getAbsolutePath()
    {
        return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->path;
    }

    public function getWebPath()
    {
        return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->path;
    }

    protected function getUploadRootDir()
    {
        return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
    }

    protected function getUploadDir()
    {

        return 'uploads/files';
    }


    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */

    public function preUpload()
    {
        if (null !== $this->FILE_file) {
                      $username=$this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()->getUsername();
            $this->path = $username.'-'.$this->path;
        }
    }

     /**
     * @ORM\PostPersist()
     * @ORM\PostUpdate()
     */

        public function upload()
    {
        // the file property can be empty if the field is not required
        if (null === $this->FILE_file) {
            return;
        }

        $this->FILE_file->move($this->getUploadRootDir(),  $this->FILE_file->getClientOriginalName());

        $this->path = $this->FILE_file->getClientOriginalName();

        $this->FILE_file = null;
    }
```

But it seems that  I can't get the container from the Entity.
So I've tried to do this in my File Controller:

```
                          $filename=$username.'-'.$file->path;

                            $file->setPath($filename);      
                            $file->setFILEFormat($ext);
                           ...

                            $em1->persist($file); 
                            $em1->flush();
                            $file->upload();
                            $content=$file->getContent();
```

getContent is a function that opens the file and stores its content in an array of strings. For some reason the file is persisted and uploaded with its OriginalName from the upload form not with $filename. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

isnt there any relation between the file an the user?
else you could do something like:

File Entity:

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM/ManyToOne(targetEntity="User" …)
 */
private $user;

public function preUpload()
{
    if (null !== $this->FILE_file) {
        $this->path = $this->user->getUsername().'-'.$this->path;
    }
}
```

Comment: For somehow the preUpload callback didn't work. I added this in the upload function and it works. Thanks.